# How to deploy create-react-app with sass

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, create-react-app

I'd like to know how to properly configure webpack (`create-react-app`) for production deployment after adding support for SASS (`npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`).

Development configuration works fine but once I run `npm build` the build fails.

Relevant snippets:

`webpack.config.dev.js`

```
loaders: [
    {
      exclude: [
        /\.html$/,
        /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        /\.css$/,
        /\.json$/,
        /\.svg$/,
        /\.scss$/
      ],
      loader: 'url',
      query: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: paths.appSrc,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }
  ]
```

`webpack.config.prod.js`

```
loaders: [
  {
    exclude: [
      /\.html$/,
      /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      /\.css$/,
      /\.json$/,
      /\.svg$/,
      /\.scss$/
    ],
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?importLoaders=1!postcss')
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there any error thrown when the build fails?